# htaccess rewrite / remove parent dir

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

there's been similar posts about this but I can't quite seem to find what I need.

I want my .htacess to rewrite "up one level". 
The Url would be somethign like
http://www.site.com/variable_dir/ 
or 
http://www.site.com/variable_dir/sub_dir

I need that to basically rewrite the request to 
http://www.site.com/ 
or 
http://www.site.com/sub_dir

I DO want the URL to still show the original 
http://www.site.com/variable_dir/ 
or 
http://www.site.com/variable_dir/sub_dir

I currently have

```
    RewriteEngine On          
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

This redirects to where I want, but this changes the URL to 
http://www.site.com/ 
or 
http://www.site.com/sub_dir
which I don't want.

I know it's simple but I just can't seem to get there.

Answer (score 1):

The rule below woule rewrite `http://www.site.com/variable_dir/` to `http://www.site.com/` and  `http://www.site.com/variable_dir/sub_dir` to `http://www.site.com/sub_dir`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#for a request to /variable_dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/variable_dir/(.+)$
#rewrite it to directory without variable_dir
RewriteRule . /%1 [L]
```

Edit:
If the directory is not literally `variable_dir`, the rule above will not work. However, if you have a short list of directories, you could enumerate them as below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#only apply if this directory does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#for any direcory enumerated here  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(variable_dir|dir2|dir3|etc)/(.+)$
#rewrite it to directory without variable_dir
RewriteRule . /%2 [L]
```

If not, then ideally the directories would all have something in common so you could limit what the rule affects. If you want a completely variable dir, nothing in common, I don't recommend it, but you can try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#only apply if this directory does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#skip any top level directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/(.+)$
#rewrite it to directory without variable_dir
RewriteRule . /%1 [L]
```

Edit:
Finally if the trailing slash is optional, as in the example in your comment, change the RewriteCond and rule above to be

```
#skip any top level directory, optional trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+(/(.+))?$
#rewrite it to directory without variable_dir
RewriteRule . /%2 [L]
```

Comment: That seems like it should work but it's not. I got a "varible_dir" not found on this server. I forgot to mention the various "variable_dirs" do not actually exist.

Comment: Is this at the top of your .htaccess? Let me know which URL you used to test

Comment: Still no luck. I have possible 12 directories, I plugged in the name of one of them and still got the same Error, "/choiceservices" not found on this server. I am using a port in the url, but I don't think that should matter. My Url is http://10.10.1.230:8091/choiceservices. The .htaccess is in the root, next to the index.php file.

Comment: Your example does not have a trailing slash. Test if it works with trailing slash. If yes, and you want trailing slash optional, then see my last edit above

Comment: In your last edit, a trailing slash gives the same "/choiceservices/" not found, and without the slash gives a 500 internal server error.

Comment: It's like it's looking for the choiceservices directory and NOT finding it, when it SHOULD be be looking for "whatever comes after"

Comment: UGGG ok, so I was typing $1 instead of %1, that was part of the problem. So I got it working EXCEPT I need the variable_dir to stay in the URL bar. So when it's at www.site.com/subdir, it should SHOW www.site.com/variable_dir/subdir.

Comment: :-).  The rule will not affect what is shown in the address bar (its a server side rewrite). If the URL in the address bar is affected, then there might be another rule that is issuing a redirect, or you have a [R] flag somewhere

Comment: Ulric, that's certainly what I thought, but I don't have [R]. My link href is "/choiceservices/dsl", but it shows in the url as "/dsl".

Comment: OK, so when there is a subdir, you can't have a trailing slash and when there isn't a subdir, you can. That's the way this works. Regex is voodoo.